# Django - Is it better to store user information by customising the default User model, or should I create a separate Model for this?

Tags: django, django-models

This is for a practice project I am building to learn Django. The site will need to track certain data about the user. Should I customise the default User model? Or create a new model like -

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    '''holds user info'''
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # data
```

I couldn't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends. I would recommend keeping `User` model small, and put most of the additional information in some kind of `Profile` model. However, there are certain important things that you may want to place in the User model, for example:

1. `user_type` field - you may have multiple Profile models (think CustomerProfile, VendorProfile etc.) and you need a way to distinguish User and grant appropriate access to them
2. Something related to authorization, like `require_2fa` field
3. If you are starting a new project and don't expect a lot of additional info, you may keep them in the `User` model just for simplicity, especially if you are already customizing it  (i.e. to replace `username` with `email`)

Answer (score 0):

Users are special so it is better to use `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser` to keep the the default user model behaviour and add your custom fields there.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

I've wrote an [article](https://simpleit.rocks/python/django/adding-users-to-your-django-project-with-custom-user-model/) about it that I think it would be userful in this case.